# update parent from child sum records

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i have created solution in visual studio 2012 and this solution is layred in 4 project :

1. project presentation layer (asp.net mvc)
2. business entities layer

   ```
   public class Parent
   {
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public decimal TotalPrice {get; set;}
     //the rest of properties
     public private ICollection<Child> Children {get; set;}
   }

   public class Child
   {
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public decimal UnitePrice {get; set;}
     //the rest of properties
     public int ParentId {get; set;}
     public private Parent Parent {get; set;}
   }
   ```
3. data access layer (ado.net data model entity framework + repositories)

   ```
   //class repository for child
   public class ParentRepository :IDisposable, IParentRepository
   {
   //implemente GetAll
      public IEnumerable<Parent>GetAllParents()
      {
         return context.parents;
      }
      public Parent GetParentById(int ParentId)
      {
         return context.Parents.Find(parentId);
      }

      //implemente GetAll CRUD for Parent
      public void AddParent(Parent parent)
      {
         context.Parents.Add(parent);
      }

      public void UpdateParent(Parent parent)
      {
         context.Parents.Attach(parent);
          context.Entry(Parents).State = EntityState.Modified;

      }

      public void DeleteParent(int parentId)
      {
         Parent parent = context.Parents.Find(parentId);
         context.Parents.Remove(parent);
      }
      // save methode
      public int Save()
      {
         return context.SaveChanges();
      }
   } 

   //class repository for child
   public class ChildRepository : IDisposable,IChildRepository
   {

   EFContext context = new EFContext();

   //Get the children for one parent

   public IEnumerable<Child> GetAllChildrenByParentId(int parentId)
   {
      var query = context.Children.Where(c=>c.ParentId == parentId)
   }

     //the rest of code to implemente CRUD of children

     public Child GetChildById(int childId)
     {
        return context.Children.Find(childId);
     }

     //implemente CRUD for Child
     public void AddChild(Child child)
     {
        context.Children.Add(child);
     }

     public void UpdateChild(Child child)
     {
       context.Children.Attach(child);
       context.Entry(child).State = EntityState.Modified;

     }

     public void DeleteChild(int childId)
     {
        Child child = context.Children.Find(childId);
        context.Children.Remove(child);
     }
     // save methode
     public int Save()
     {
        return context.SaveChanges();
     }
   }
   ```
4. but for business logic layer in classes Bll i try to calculate the total of the Parent by sum of unit prices for the children

   ```
   public class ParentChildBll
   {
     //retreive the parent by its parentid
      public Parent GetParent(int parentId){
         using (var repository = new ParentRepository())
         {       
           return repository.GetParentById(parentId);
         }  
      }
      public decimal GetTotal(int parentId)
      {
         int total;
         //call the GetParent() methode for getting parent to update its totalprice
         Parent parent = GetParent(parentId);
         //call the methode GetAllChildrenByParentId of ChildRepository that return 
        //ienumerebal<Child> and then call the extention methode Sum for calculate 
       // the sum of unite prices of child

        using (var repository = new ChildRepository())
        {       
           var query = reopsitory.GetAllChildrenByParentId(parentId).Sum(d=>d.UnitePrice);
          total=query;
        }

        parent.TotalPrice =total;
        UpdateParent(parent);//call update parent
        return total;
    }
    //implement crud parent
    public void UpdateParent(Parent parent)
    {
      //call repository update methode in BLL class
      using (var repository = new ParentRepository())
      {       
          reopsitory.UpdateParent(parent);
          repository.Save();
      }
      //
     }
   }
   ```

What I have tried:

-every time i insert/update/delete child i have to call getTotal() methode for update the parent totalprice in ParentChildBLL class,

```
public void AddChild(Child child)
{
   //call repository update methode in BLL class
   using (var repository = new ChildRepository())
   {       
       reopsitory.AddChild(child);
       repository.Save();
   }
   //update totalPrice of parent each insertion of child
   getTotal(child.ParentId);
}
```

is there an implementation better for update parent total by sum of each child unitprice when the child inserted/updated/deleted

-i don't know where do calculte sum have to be implemented, in repositories or in Bll?

I would be grateful if you helped me

goodby soon

Comment: Are you storing the calculated parent price in the database after calculation? Why? It could be a calculated value.

Comment: but it is calculted from child property, not from parent property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, we avoid storing calculated properties but it may be useful if:

- child entities are involved, and
- child entities are updated less often than a parent entity is retrieved.

> is there an implementation better for update parent total by sum of each child unitprice when the child inserted/updated/deleted

Consider updating the difference:

```
public class ParentChildBll
{
    public decimal UpdateTotal(int parentId, decimal oldUnitPrice, decimal newUnitPrice)
    {
        var parent = GetParent(parentId);
        parent.TotalPrice += newUnitPrice - oldUnitPrice;
        UpdateParent(parent);
    }

    public void AddChild(Child child)
    {
        var oldUnitPrice = 0m;
        var newUnitPrice = child.UnitePrice;

        using (var repository = new ChildRepository())
        {
            repository.AddChild(child);
            repository.Save();
        }

        UpdateTotal(child.ParentId, oldUnitPrice, newUnitPrice);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you but what do you mean by "In general, we avoid storing calculated properties but it may be useful if:

child entities are involved, and
child entities are updated less often than a parent entity is retrieved."

Comment: how child entities are involved?, and
how child entities are updated less often than a parent entity is retrieved?  
and in case of updateChild what do oldunitPrice, newUnitPrice become?
on what are assigned?

Comment: yes i am and i want to inderstand when calculated properties but it may be useful

Comment: but it's not seldom modified it's modified each child crud. and in case of updateChild what do oldunitPrice, newUnitPrice become? on what are assigned?

Comment: yes i knew but in case of child update,on what are assigned these variable?

Comment: i mean that how to get oldunitprice and newuniteprice for child that going to be updated?

Comment: 'public void UpdateChild(Child child)
                {
                     var oldUnitPrice = ?;
                     var newUnitPrice = ?;

                     using (var repository = new ChildRepository())
                       {
                             repository.UpdateChild(child);
                            repository.Save();
                      }

                    UpdateTotal(child.ParentId, oldUnitPrice, newUnitPrice);
                }'

Comment: i don't inderstand what's this methode so?

Comment: i want to know var oldUnitPrice = ?; var newUnitPrice = ? in this methode

Comment: in class ParentChildBll this is like AddChild methode

Answer (score 0):

In EF code first, you can use `computed column` to store `TotalPrice`. It should be a `read-only` field.

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public decimal TotalPrice
    {
        get
        {
            return Children == null ? 0 : Children.Sum(x => x.UnitePrice);
        }
    }

    //the rest of properties
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use a sum function in your linq code for get parents from database

for exemple for you code in business layer

```
 public IEnumerable<Parent>GetAllParents()
 {
      return context.parents.Select(p=> new Parent 
      {
       Id = p.Id,
       TotalPrice = p.Children.Sum(x=>x.UnitePrice)
      });
}
```

and i think there's not need to UpdateTotal Methode